# Nuclear to Electricity Energy Conversion

Tags: energy, electricity, nuclear-physics, power, nuclear-engineering

Currently nuclear power generates heat, which heats water into steam that turns conventional turbines. The energy conversion is as follows:
photonic->heat->kinetic->electric

This would result in low efficiency. However, I thought up of an idea that I would like to put forth. I'd like to check if such an idea would work though XD.

[image: Diagram]

A sphere made of an electron-rich element/molecule is placed within a nuclear reactor. It is connected to the Earth outside of the reactor. A positive electric field is generated at one side of the reactor. When the reactor is started, there will be all 3 forms of radiation generated (gamma, alpha and beta).

The following reactions are what I forsee would occur:

1. The gamma rays would rip electrons off the sphere (essentially ionising the sphere) which would then create a potential difference (pd) across the wire as charges move from the Earth to the sphere.
2. The beta particles would knock electrons off the sphere and bounce around the reactor chamber until their energies are low enough to be trapped within the electric field. The sphere would get ionised and the pd would be generated similar to (1).
3. The alpha particles, being much larger and having a lower velocity due to their larger mass, would bounce around the reactor chamber and react with the ripped off electrons to form He. This He could then be removed. This would prevent a buildup of electrons in the reaction chamber.

I read about the issue of photodisintegration. Such an occurrence would require the sphere to be replaced frequently. Along with this, there is also the issue of transmutation of the atoms in the sphere due to the neutrons in the reaction chamber. However, I believe using a more stable atom (like Fe) would be able to reduce this? (Not very sure if that is how it works)

I would just like to know if such a system would work :)

Thanks
Isaac

Comment: You should look into direct energy conversion. Stanley Angrist's "Direct Energy Conversion" is a solid book on the topic. Additionally Ralph Moir, William Barr, and George H. Miley, have done significant work in the field, and have many interesting publications, though admittedly with applications to fusion power.

Comment: *photonic->heat->kinetic->electric.* But, majority of energy is kinetic energy of particles and not photonic. It should be like *kinetic->heat->kinetic->electric*

Answer (score 0):

> A sphere made of an electron-rich element/molecule is placed within a nuclear reactor.

The basic flaw is that the reactor core is composed of metal containers, [fuel rods,](http://www.world-nuclear.org/information-library/nuclear-fuel-cycle/conversion-enrichment-and-fabrication/fuel-fabrication.aspx) containing the fuel pellets, so no charge would build up. Insulators would melt in the reactor so the process is no go.

If one could insulate with a vacuum (for example)  the sphere would gather energy through a surface, a very small part of the energy provided would be gathered.

Generally heat which is the effect of energy transferred by low frequency photons has much larger crossection in interacting with matter than individual decaying particles , so even surrounding a reactor with a conducting surface the efficiency would be much lower, imo as I have not done any calculations.

In fusion reactors temperatures of plasma are enormous, much larger than the melting point of a metal.

Comment: The reactor that I was referring to would be a fission reactor :) as for the sphere, it is not the same as the reactor fuel. It is simply a sphere that will be used to generate the pd required

Comment: As a conductor all metals are more or less the same.Uranium is a metal. As far as electrons go they do not care if the metal is radioactive or not. That is why I am referring to insulation.

Comment: But wouldn't a charge build, even on a metal, if electrons are removed from it?

Comment: yes , but the whole reactor is metal, you do not need the sphere. Maybe different geometry reactors. Still the crossection for charge build up will be much smaller than for heat build up.

Comment: Hmm, would a better design be used to exploit both the heat buildup and the charge buildup? Also i thought reactors had concrete walls haha

Comment: The concrete is outside the core. One would have to calculate how much energy a charge build up on a periphery  would generate, and the problems to the way the reactor works, ( rods etc) this will create.

Comment: I guess a suitable insulator for the wire to prevent contact with the metal side of the reactor would be concrete? That shouldn't melt as fast right? (Sorry for the noob questions haha)

Comment: If you introduce insulators like that in the core, the core would stop being critical, so no energy. If you are really interested you should take a course in reactor technology or some such,  to learn the tools for calculating processes.

Comment: Re: "Uranium is also a metal"; The fuel pellets in most reactors are a ceramic made from uranium and maybe also plutonium oxides.  But of course, the fuel pellets are loaded into metallic (Zircalloy) tubes.

Comment: @jameslarge  Thanks , obviously I did not know that, I will edit

Answer (score 0):

@anna v gave some correct weak points of your design but I think there are more general points to make. I want to add some more general points about nuclear fission reactors or fission itself.

As @Anubhav Goel commented on the question: most of the fission energy is kinetic: typically about 70% as kinetic energy of the daughter nuclei, a few percent for fast neutrons and other fission fragments. Then granted the rest is radiation: about 10% in mostly delayed beta (and occasional alpha decays) and about 5% in gamma radiation. The kinetic energy is at the end thermal energy.

A nuclear reactor core is emerged in water, to cool it and get away thermal energy. That water is necessary because it needs to be cooled. You can get the kinetic energy out quiet efficiently and generating electrical energy from steam is not that inefficient: very modern turbines/generators can get up to maybe 40%-50% efficiency  I think (someone correct me here if I am wrong).

Now to the radiation: forget about beta particles knocking electrons from spheres: they will never reach the walls of the reactor because their range in water is to small. A rule of thump is 0.5cm  acrylic glass will block almost all beta radiation. For alpha particles it is even worse: a sheet of paper will stop them. In the water of the reactor core only a very very small fraction of the alpha and beta radiation will get near the walls. So you really do not have to worry about getting the energy of alpha and beta radiation with some complicated mechanism: water will get that energy whether you want it or not.

So we are left with only about 5% of the fission energy in gamma radiation of which some part will be dissipated inside the reactor. So only a very small fraction of the total fission energy is getting outside of the reactor.

For a fission reactor there is just not much radiation left. Apart from that, I kind of doubt that one could convert all/most of radiation energy directly into electricity at the end you will always end up with a lot of thermic energy I suppose.

I think modern fission reactors are maybe as efficient as they can get to be honest apart from maybe some engineering tweaking on turbines and so on and using the excess/residual heat for heating. The concept itself can not be improved in its core I am afraid. This last section is more a gut feeling of mine without knowing to much about "real" turbine/reactor efficiency.

For fusion reactors the situation will be a similar one: most of the energy leaving the reactor core will be in form of neutrons: capturing them will be the mayor challenge of the energy generation aspect of the reactor. A breeding blanket will be most likely used to absorb the neutron radiation and breed tritium in the process. This blanket will heat up and this heat will be used to generate energy. At least that is the hope/plan.

We will not get rid of our good old steam machines for a long time.